# Difference between declaration

Tags: c#, .net, declaration, nullable

What is the difference between these two codes :

```
public uint? a;
public uint a;
```

I want to know what is the difference if we use ? after int or double or the others

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`uint?` is a [nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), it can hold null value, for example.

```
uint? a;
uint b;

a = null;
b = null; //this will cause error
```

in C# 4.0 you can check using [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
    b = a ?? 0;
```

its same as

```
    if (a.HasValue)
        b = a;
    else
        b = 0;
```

Comment: `b = a ?? 0` and `if (a.HasValue) b = 0` are not equivalent.  That should be `if (a.HasValue) b = a; else b = 0;`

Comment: @TimS., oh yes, missed it. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Value types can't hold null value as they are not objects. With ? you specify that you want to use an invisible wrapper around your value type, and let it be null.

```
int a = null  // won't work
int? b = null // works
```

Answer (score 4):

`int?` is a shortcut to `Nullable<int>`. It allows null values to be stored. `Nullable<T>` is a generic type that allows assignment of a null value to types not normally support null values.

So

```
int? a = null; //valid
int b = null; //invalid

//usage pattern
if (a.HasValue){
    c = a.Value;
}
```

See [Nullable MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
public uint? a is `nullable type` which is what the `?` operator means in this scenario.

public uint a; is an unsigned integer that requires a value.
```

Nullable types are instances of the System.Nullable struct. A nullable type can represent the normal range of values for its underlying value type, plus an additional null value. For example, a Nullable, pronounced "Nullable of Int32," can be assigned any value from -2147483648 to 2147483647, or it can be assigned the null value. A Nullable can be assigned the values true or false, or null. The ability to assign null to numeric and Boolean types is particularly useful when dealing with databases and other data types containing elements that may not be assigned a value. For example, a Boolean field in a database can store the values true or false, or it may be undefined.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

One thing to add:

```
public uint? a;
```

is exactly the same as

```
public Nullable<uint> a;
```

the `?` is just syntactic sugar.

Oh, and another one that comes to mind: just because the framework gives you the option to use [nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx), it doesn't mean you should use them without thinking.

When you use them, your code will be littered with calls to Nullable's `HasValue` checks, which, being the same as `x == null`, might point to a design that can be improved.

I'm not saying Nullables are bad. Quite the opposite, actually: if you think they might fit your use case perfectly, then by all means go ahead and use them.

Just don't use them only because they are there. Please? Pretty please?

Answer (score 2):

`public uint? a;` This is nullable type. A nullable type can represent the correct range of values for its underlying value type, plus an additional null value.